# Design tables for data in excel sheet

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I am new in DB design,need advice to design correct number of tables and columns from excel sheet with this columns:

[image: example:]

If multiple locations available or Foil is Y for a cardname then you see multiple rows for that cardname.

Comment: if i understand it right, you should create 3 tables, every table will have a first column of id (int, identity field),1'st table will be the main one, it will be like that table but instead of Foil column content of N and Y it will have id's (foreign key) of the 2'nd table- Foil, will have 2 columns, id, the foil letter. the 2'rd on will be locations, again, 2 columns- id and locationName (the id's will be in the first table..in the location column. - tell me if it's enough

Answer (score 0):

Identify the *entities* that your data model needs to represent.

An entity is briefly defined as:  a person, place, thing, concept or event that can be *uniquely identified*, is *important* to the business, and we can *store information* about.

Also, identify the *relationships* between the entities.

The usual approach is consultation with the data owner/system owner; asking appropriate questions, throwing some ideas down in an entity relationship model, and asking further questions reviewing what is right about the model, and what isn't... altering and refining the model.

From the very brief description in the question, we would likely propose, as a starting point, some proposed entities:  *card* and *location*.

Identify candidate keys:

What uniquely identifies a card?

What uniquely identifies a location?

Identify the cardinality of relationships (how many on each side of the relationship?

Can a location be related to more than one card?

Can a card have more than one location?

Must a card be related to a location (can we have a card that doesn't have a location?

etc.

Then, then assign the non-key attributes to the appropriate entities. Aim for third normal form.

"*Each attribute is dependent on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key. So help me Codd.*"